# Ignoring substitution variable when condition is not satisfied

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How to ignore a substitution variable when the condition is not met, but 
Oracle always prompts it from the user?

```
declare
    vari_axu number;
begin
    if &param = 1 then
        dbms_output.put_line ('work here ');

        select count(*) into vari_axu from &mytable;
        dbms_output.put_line (vari_axu);
        return;
    end if;

    dbms_output.put_line ('do not work' );
end;
```

Even if condition `&param = 1` is not met, Oracle still prompts for `&mytable`.
How to avoid it?

Comment: The variables are substituted (and prompted for) by the client before the resulting code is compiled and executed on the server; you can see that if you `set verify on`. You can't have user-input directly in PL/SQL, so the logic doesn't work inside it either. You could do something messy with nested scripts, but even in this simple demo it's a bit nasty, and presumably your real scenario is rather more complicated already.

Comment: Thanks,   is there any chance to change the logic of the script?

Comment: The best you can do is have the script conditionally call other scripts. It gets messy. If possible it would be better to use a scripting language.

Comment: can you suggest how to call other script from the main script?

Comment: Who is the "user" in this case? Why are they bothered by entering a value which is possibly not required?

Answer (score 1):

SQL*Plus script for Windows:

```
set define "&"
set verify off
define mytable = dual

accept param prompt "Enter option 1-9: "

-- Generate a script named prompt_for_tablename.sql which prompts the user for a table name
-- or does nothing, depending on the value of &param:
set termout off
column mytable new_value mytable
set head off feedback off
spool prompt_for_tablename.sql
select 'accept mytable char prompt "Enter table name: "' as prompt from dual where &param = 1;
spool off
set termout on head on feedback on

@prompt_for_tablename.sql
host del prompt_for_tablename.sql

declare
    vari_axu number;
begin
    if &param = 1 then
        dbms_output.put_line ('work here');
        select count(*) into vari_axu from &mytable ;
        dbms_output.put_line('Count of &mytable: ' || vari_axu);
        return;
    end if;

    dbms_output.put_line ('do not work' );
end;
/
```

If the user enters `1` at the first prompt, the generated script `prompt_for_tablename.sql` will prompt for a table name. For any other value, it will do nothing.

Then `prompt_for_tablename.sql` is run (and immediately deleted, as we don't need it any more). Now `&mytable` contains either its default value from the start of the script, or whatever the user entered at the prompt.

**Added: version with two variables**

This builds a dynamic query as:

```
select count(*) into vari_axu from &mytable where created > date '&busdate';
```

For demo purposes you can enter the table name as `user_objects` (where `created` is a date column).

Obviously this kind of construction gets complicated and error-prone as the user must specify a table that has the expected column name, so I'm not sure I recommend going too far down this path, but anyway:

```
set define "&"
set verify off
define mytable = dual
define busdate = "0001-01-01"
define if_param_is_1 = "--"

accept param prompt "Enter option 1-9: "

-- Generate a script named prompt_for_tablename.sql which prompts the user for a table name
-- or does nothing, depending on the value of &param:
set termout off
column mytable new_value mytable
column if_param_is_1 new_value if_param_is_1

set head off feedback off
spool prompt_for_tablename.sql
select prompt, null as if_param_is_1  -- uncomment
from
(
  select 'accept mytable char prompt "Enter table name: "'||chr(13)||chr(10) as prompt from dual
  union all
  select 'accept busdate date format ''YYYY-MM-DD'' prompt "Enter business date (YYYY-MM-DD): "' from dual
)
where &param = 1;
spool off
set termout on head on feedback on

@prompt_for_tablename.sql
host del prompt_for_tablename.sql

declare
    vari_axu number;
begin
    &if_param_is_1 dbms_output.put_line ('work here');
    &if_param_is_1 select count(*) into vari_axu from &mytable where created > date '&busdate';
    &if_param_is_1 dbms_output.put_line('Count of &mytable created after &busdate: ' || vari_axu);
    &if_param_is_1 return;

    dbms_output.put_line ('do not work' );
end;
/
```

Test passing param as 2:

```
SQL> @demo
Enter option 1-9: 2

do not work

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Test passing param as 1:

```
SQL> @demo
Enter option 1-9: 1
Enter table name: user_objects
Enter business date (YYYY-MM-DD): 2010-01-01

work here
Count of user_objects created after 2010-01-01: 93772

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

(You can suppress the `successfully completed` messages with `set feedback off`.)

Comment: what if i need two substitution variables? should i have two scripts?

Comment: You should be able to combine the two prompts in the same temporary script.

Comment: How could i do this? you mean in the same select?

Comment: A second `select` in the same spoolfile. Would this be a second parameter like `&param` and a second variable like `&mytable`?

Comment: it will be seconde variable like &mytable

Comment: And a second parameter like `&param`?

Comment: No Just the same condition means (if &param = 1 then) but in the count condition i have to add another parameter like &mytable