# user input at specific conditions in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I was wondering that can you ask user for input at specific conditions?

I tried in my case and place the input `&some_thing` in a condition but even when the conditions are not met it is still asking for input

Has anyone else tried this?

I am using toad for oracle

```
  CASE DECODE(INITCAP(PA.ADDRESS_LINE1),'mycountry','NOT FOREIGN','FOREIGN')
                     WHEN 'FOREIGN' THEN TO_CHAR(&CRITERIA*PPP.PROPOSED_SALARY_N)
                     ELSE
                     TO_CHAR(PPP.PROPOSED_SALARY_N) END AS NEW_SALARY,
```

Comment: Punctuation exists for reason; use it. Apart from that, could you, please, explain what you mean? What "specific conditions"? Which tool do you use? Share code you wrote (doesn't matter it doesn't work, it'll help us figure out what you want).

Comment: What toad does is to replace the value similar to a macro. Toad is just a client, not a interpreter/compiler, it just replaces the value and pass it to oracle server to process it. there is no communication to and forth between server(oracle) and client(toad).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignoring substitution variable when condition is not satisfied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48498926/ignoring-substitution-variable-when-condition-is-not-satisfied)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for editing the question & providing additional information.

As far as I can tell, you can't do that. TOAD (as well as SQL*Plus) will ask you for parameter's value, regardless of whether the condition is met or not.

But, why does that bother you? Provide its value and let query return the result.

Comment: i don't want oracle to prompt user every time.. but only on those persons who does not belong to mycountry